# Why can I not release this NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

Here is the relevant code:

```
NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [defaultServer root]];
address = [address stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", [defaultServer login]];
address = [address stringByAppendingFormat:@"?%@", [params urlEncodedString]];

NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] init];
response = [self getResponseFromWebAddress:address];

[response release];
[address release];
```

This code does not error here, but later inside of some Apple Libraries it throws a "message sent to deallocated instance" error.  However, if I comment out the line `[address release]` it works fine.  Why?  I don't quite understand memory management and this one confuses me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [defaultServer root]];
```

And its following lines all work with autoreleased `NSString`s supplied by the `stringWithFormat:` and `stringByAppendingFormat:` methods. You're not supposed to release `address` manually, since the autorelease pool will handle that for you.

And here:

```
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] init];
response = [self getResponseFromWebAddress:address];
```

You are allocating a new `NSString`, then immediately pointing the `response` variable to another string which is autoreleased (`[self getResponseFromWebAddress:address]`). The allocated object no longer has any available pointers, so you can't release it anymore, and therefore it leaks.

To fix both issues, remove the alloc-init line and the release lines. Your `address` string can also be initialized with just one statement:

```
// Combine all three arguments into one format string
NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?%@", 
                        [defaultServer root], 
                        [defaultServer login], 
                        [params urlEncodedString]];

NSString *response = [self getResponseFromWebAddress:address];

// No need to release either variable
```

Comment: Thank you for such a well crafted and explained answer!

Answer (score 2):

Remember the NARC (new, alloc, retain, copy) rule.
You have to release an object only if it was created by one of these messages.
Otherwise the object will be autoreleased.

Comment: I have never heard of the NARC rule before.  So I'm guessing that means something like this `NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:username, @"username", password, @"password", nil];` I WOULD need to release since I called it with `initWithObjectsAndKeys`.  Thank you for teaching me something new!

Comment: No actually. That's being created by -alloc (your [NSDictionary alloc]), and *initialized* (not created) by -initWithObjectsAndKeys:. Therefore you do need to release that. Also, a typo in the original answer: it's -copy, not -clone.

Comment: Think the `clone` should be `copy` ;-)

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Thanks for fixing it.